# Why would a maven-war-plugin generate a JAR instead of a WAR?

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-plugin, maven-war-plugin

I am following [this](https://mvnwls.wordpress.com/2011/02/01/contract-first-cxf/) *Contract first using CXF* tutorial and while the resulting `pom.xml` generates sources and even **completes build successfully**, it fails to create a WAR file.

Instead, it creates a JAR file.

My understanding is that the part in the [pom.xml](https://mvnwls.wordpress.com/2011/02/01/contract-first-cxf/) that's responsible for creating the WAR is:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.1</version>
  <configuration>
    <outputDirectory>D:/path/to/profile/autodeploy</outputDirectory>
  </configuration>
 </plugin>
```

I don't see any `<goal>` or `<execution>` element there (unlike in the `build-helper-maven-plugin` one), but I also understand that with this plugin this is implied as even the [official usage page](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin//usage.html) demonstrates:

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <configuration>
          <webappDirectory>/sample/servlet/container/deploy/directory</webappDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

So... what am I missing?

What could possibly explain a `maven-war-plugin` that behaves in unexpected way like this and produces a JAR instead of a WAR by default?

Is there a way to force it to produce a WAR?

Comment: should there be a `<packaging>war</packaging>` somewhere in the POM?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

packaging should be as below.

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

if it won't help then try binding your plug-in configuration with a lifecycle phase.

Answer (score 8):

in your project definition , please check if packaging is missing or not , it should be some thing like this .

```
   <groupId>some.groupid</groupId>
   <artifactId>My Web Application</artifactId>
   <version>0.0.1</version>
   <packaging>war</packaging>
   <description>My First Web Application</description>
```

By default maven war plugin binds to `package phase of the lifecycle` ,so its important that we should mention the type of packaging we want once the build is done.

I would like to suggest to have a look at the [Maven specs for war plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/).